# What is the correct way to remove a font from multiple HTML files without manual update?

Tags: html, css, fonts, webfonts

Currently, I am using a font for emails ...let's call is - "FontX"

In all the email  template (html), the "Font X" is being used everywhere. Now that I am looking to cancel the license of the font, I need to make sure font is not being used or referenced anywhere in the email templates.

**Issue:** Going through thousands of email templates / HTML is not feasible and requires a lot of manual work

**Possible solution:** Need some feedback on this, if this is a right approach?

In the email templates / HTML, "FontX" is being used everywhere like inline etc.

```
style="font-family:'FontX', Arial, Times New Roman, sans-serif;
```

Along with that, CSS file is being referenced in HTML as well.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fontx.css" />
```

My question, what if I remove font-face reference in the referenced CSS file? It will break the source and even though font name is being used in HTML, "Font X" usage will be over, correct?

Currently, the references CSS file includes something like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontX';
    src: url('FontX.eot');
    src: url('FontX.ttf') format('truetype'),         
         url('FontX') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    mso-font-alt: 'Times New Roman';
}
```

What will happen if I remove **src** lines?

What font will be used as a fall back?
What is the use of **mso-font-alt**? Is this considered a fall back font?

Comment: On websites, we don't use spaces in file names. This is because you can't have spaces in URLs, so that means that browsers/servers will handle them inconsistently, and replace them with %20 or something. Google recommends replacing them with dashes. Also, change your capital letters to lowercase, for the same reason. So "Font X.eot" becomes "font-x.eot". Thanks

Comment: The "correct" way is to remove the references from every file. The "correct" way to have added references to the font fact in the first place was to use `font-family: 'Font X', 'Times New Roman', serif;` so that the removal of Font X would cause little issue.

Comment: Hi @sven thanks for your comment and point out the space. That was a typo from my end which I have corrected in the question above. Apart of space typo, do you have any suggestions regarding my question about removal of font?

Comment: Hi @HereticMonkey Thank you for your comments. Yes, I understand that "correct" way is to remove the reference completely but since I am talking about updating / fixing thousands of email files where font is being reference, it may not be feasible since it required a lot of manual work. Hence, I am asking some suggestions / workaround where I do not have to go for manual updat. I have added in my question how font is being used in the html inline like this: `font-family:'FontX', Arial, Times New Roman, sans-serif`.

Comment: Hi @HereticMonkey Now that other font names are specified along with "FontX", what should I do to remove the font? Should I simply remove references **font.css** stylesheet from **<head>**? OR should I delete all **src** lines from the font.css file where location of "FontX" is mentioned? Also - when we have multiple fonts defined like `font-family:'FontX', Arial, Times New Roman, sans-serif`, if "FontX" is not found, then other fonts are used as fall back? Just looking for some guidance here.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family for how `font-family` works.

Comment: Thank you @HereticMonkey for the useful reference. It is helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to remove the font from the email template. One is better than the other. Unfortunately you can't just get rid of the src lines, as we need a place to find the font. It's just like an `img` without an actual image to find. And it wont go back to the `mso-font-alt`. I will explain

## The changing-the-src-way (the best method)

If I understood correctly, you don't want to use the font anymore in anything you do. So what you could do is change the lines with the src in them. You could, if you want, change them to a new font, however don't get rid of them.

`mso` stands for Microsoft Office (this is because in Outlook, HTML emails are read with Microsoft Word!). So this is probably an alternative for Microsoft Word.

## The getting-rid-of-the-whole-thing way

This is not the best method, but you could just get rid of the whole `@font-face` bit. This would make it go back to the fallback font, which you specified in the `style` attribute in all your emails.